# Using Twitter in Python IDE

Tags: python, twitter

I am really new to Python and I want to use the Twitter API on PyCharm but it kept on telling me that it isn't recognized.

I ran Tweeter API using just the terminal and it works. But, with the terminal it has limited functionality, hence I want to use the IDE instead.

So;
A) what is the difference between Python on the terminal and the IDE?
B) How would I install and run Twitter API on the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

First, please specify what "Twitter API" you are using with your terminal.
There are Twitter API provided by Twitter and various wrapper libraries for Python.

For your question:

- A) Technically No. But if you can tell me your OS and your terminal
  Python version, maybe I can help you more :)
- B) Depends on "which Twitter API" question at first.